# how to increase the count of frequently occuring words using java

Tags: java, dictionary, count, word-frequency

Hi below is my program which displays top 10 frequently occuring words but my requirement is to get top 30 frequently occuring words,

```
class FrequencyCount {
int[][] table = new int[4][1000000];
TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>(
            Collections.reverseOrder());
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FrequencyCount freq = new FrequencyCount();
        BufferedReader br = null;
try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "C:/portable.pdf")));
        String fileline = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("fileline:" + fileline);
        while (fileline != null) {
            if (fileline.length() > 0) {
                String[] sArr = fileline.split(" ");
                for (String s : sArr) {
                    int flag = 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < stopwords.length; j++) {
                        String s1 = s.toLowerCase();

                    }
                    if (flag != 0) {
                        if (s.trim().length() > 0) {
                            try {
                                freq.add(freq.trimStr(s));
                            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            fileline = br.readLine();
        }

        Set<Integer> set = freq.map.keySet();
        for (Integer x : set) {
            System.out.println(freq.map.get(x) + " found " + x + " times");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}

public String trimStr(String s) {
    if (s.toUpperCase().equals(s.toLowerCase())) {
        return s;
    }
    s = s.toLowerCase().trim();

    if (s.endsWith("'s")) {
        s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2);
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = s.length() - 1;
    char[] cArr = s.toCharArray();

    while (!(cArr[i] >= 65 && cArr[i] <= 90)
            && !(cArr[i] >= 97 && cArr[i] <= 122)) {
        i++;
    }

    while (!(cArr[j] >= 65 && cArr[j] <= 90)
            && !(cArr[j] >= 97 && cArr[j] <= 122)) {
        j--;
    }

    return s.substring(i, j + 1);
}

public int[] hash(String s) {
    int h1 = hash1(s);
    int h2 = hash2(s);
    int h3 = hash3(s);
    int h4 = hash4(s);

    int[] res = new int[] { h1, h2, h3, h4 };
    return res;
}

public int hash1(String x) {
    char ch[] = x.toCharArray();
    int i, sum;
    for (sum = 0, i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
        sum += ch[i];
    return sum % 1000000;
}

public int hash2(String s) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        h = 31 * h + s.charAt(i);
    }
    h = h % 1000000;
    if (h < 0) {
        h = -h;
    }
    return h;
}

public int hash3(String s) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        h = 17 * h + s.charAt(i);
    }
    h = h % 1000000;
    if (h < 0) {
        h = -h;
    }
    return h;
}

public int hash4(String s) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        h = 11 * h + s.charAt(i);
    }
    h = h % 1000000;
    if (h < 0) {
        h = -h;
    }
    return h;
}

public void add(String s) {

    int[] h = hash(s);
    table[0][h[0]] = table[0][h[0]] + 1;
    table[1][h[1]] = table[1][h[1]] + 1;
    table[2][h[2]] = table[2][h[2]] + 1;
    table[3][h[3]] = table[3][h[3]] + 1;
    int r = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(table[0][h[0]], table[1][h[1]]),
            table[2][h[2]]), table[3][h[3]]);
    boolean add = true;
    List<String> list = map.get(r);
    if (list == null) {
        if (map.size() == 10) {
            Integer lastKey = map.lastKey();
            if (lastKey.intValue() > r) {
                add = false;
            } else {
                map.remove(lastKey);
            }
        }
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    if (add) {
        list.add(s);
        map.put(r, list);
        if (r > 1) {
            list = map.get(r - 1);
            if (list != null) {
                if (list.size() == 1) {
                    map.remove(r - 1);
                } else {
                    list.remove(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public int count(String s) {
    int[] h = hash(s);
    int a = table[0][h[0]];
    int b = table[1][h[1]];
    int c = table[2][h[2]];
    int d = table[3][h[3]];
    int r = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c), d);
    return r;
}
}
```

I have changed the map size to 30, but its not working, please suggest me how to get top 30 frequently occurring words.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach. I would add store the word in a HashMap instead and use the string in lowercase as key and then number of time it occured as the value. When the entire map is created you can sort it as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) and display any number from the top as you like.

The general idea:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> wordcounter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    if (wordcounter.containsKey(s))
        wordcounter.put(s, wordcounter.get(s) + 1);
    else
        wordcounter.put(s, 1);
```

Comment: is it possible to get n number of frequently occurring words by using my code, if not i will try this procedure, can u please suggest me.

Comment: Im not quite sure about this. You stated that you had changed the size of the map to 30 but it didn't work. Did you update this line in the add-method aswell?

"if (map.size() == 10) {"

Otherwise i guess that could do the trick

Answer (score 0):

There is only one word change from 10 to 30 as mentioned below.

```
public void add(String s) {

    int[] h = hash(s);
    table[0][h[0]] = table[0][h[0]] + 1;
    table[1][h[1]] = table[1][h[1]] + 1;
    table[2][h[2]] = table[2][h[2]] + 1;
    table[3][h[3]] = table[3][h[3]] + 1;
    int r = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(table[0][h[0]], table[1][h[1]]),
            table[2][h[2]]), table[3][h[3]]);
    boolean add = true;
    List<String> list = map.get(r);
    if (list == null) {
        if (map.size() == 30) {//Changed from 10 to 30

            Integer lastKey = map.lastKey();
            if (lastKey.intValue() > r) {
                add = false;
            } else {
                map.remove(lastKey);
            }
        }
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    if (add) {
        list.add(s);
        map.put(r, list);
        if (r > 1) {
            list = map.get(r - 1);
            if (list != null) {
                if (list.size() == 1) {
                    map.remove(r - 1);
                } else {
                    list.remove(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also Comment 3 lines // for (int j = 0; j < stopwords.length; j++) {
                 //       String s1 = s.toLowerCase();

                  //  }